# CQRS: Can the write model consume a read model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

When reading about CQRS it is often mentioned that the write model should not depend on any read model (assuming there is one write model and up to N read models). This makes a lot of sense, especially since read models usually only become eventually consistent with the write model. Also, we should be able to change or replace read models without breaking the write model.

However, read models might contain valuable information that is aggregated across many entities of the write model. These aggregations might even contain non-trivial business rules. One can easily imagine a **business policy** that evaluates a piece of information that a read model possesses, and in reaction to that changes one or many entities via the write model. But where should this policy be located/implemented? Isn't this critical business logic that tightly couples information coming from one particular read model with the write model?

When I want to implement said policy without coupling the write model to the read model, I can imagine the following strategy: Include a **materialized view** in the write model that gets updated synchronously whenever a relevant part of the involved entities changes (when using DDD, this could be done via domain events). However, this denormalizes the write model, and is effectively a special read model embedded in the write model itself.

I can imagine that DDD purists would say that such a policy should not exist, because it represents a business invariant/rule that encompasses multiple entities (a.k.a. aggregates). I could probably agree in theory, but in practice, I often encounter such requirements anyway.

Finally, my **question** is simply: How do you deal with requirements that change data in reaction to certain conditions whose evaluation requires a read model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read a lot about the topic and having thought hard about it myself, I attempt to answer my own question.

First, a clarification about the terms used. The write and read models *themselves* never have any dependency to one another. The corresponding command and query components might have instead. I will therefore call the entirety of the command component and its write model the **command side**, and the entirety of one particular query component and its read model a **query side** (of which there might be many).

So consider a command handler that is responsible for evaluating and executing a business policy. It takes a command DTO, validates it, loads part of the write model into memory, and applies changes to it in one atomic transaction. The question specifically was, whether this handler is allowed to query one of the query sides in order to inform its decision about what to do in the write model.

The answer would be a resounding **NO**. Here's why:

- The command side would depend on one particular query side (it doesn't matter if you hide the dependency behind an interface – it is still there), so the query side cannot change independently.
- Who actually guarantees that the command handler runs when it has to? The query side is certainly not the one responsible for it, and clients aren't either.
- The command request is prolonged by performing a nested query request, which might be detrimental to the performance.

Instead, we can do the following:

- Work with domain events raised by the write model, register a domain event handler in the command side that evaluates the policy. This way it is guaranteed that the policy will be executed whenever it has to be.
- If the performance allows it, this domain event handler can simply load as much of the write model as it requires to evaluate the business condition. Don't prematurely optimize – maybe the entities are small and can easily be loaded into memory.
- If the performance does not allow it, *denormalize* the write model and maintain the required statistics using domain events. No one says that the write model cannot itself contain query-oriented data. Being a write model simply says that it is *a model designed to do writes*, and this necessarily must include some means to read as well.
- Finally, if applying the policy is *not an integral part of the domain logic* itself, but rather just a use case, consider putting the responsibility of calling it into a client or another microservice, where it is totally fine to first query one of our query sides, and afterwards calling our command side with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: I have to add the following: The event handler in the command side is still eventually consistent. You are in danger of making decisions based on stale information. There are ways to tackle this situation, but transaccional guarantees is not easy to achieve with event handlers that are "chasing" the current state in a active database with lots of writes happening every second.

Comment: @Narvalex what would you propose as alternative solution? Or how could transactional guarantees be achieved in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve transactional guarantees, at the cost of performance, just like a typical Relational Database with ACID guarantees. Is not easy to explain the solution in a comment of a SO thread, but it you want to know more about it just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First, any write model which validates commands is a read model (because at some point validating a command requires a read), albeit one that is optimized for the purpose of validating commands.  So I'm not sure where you're seeing that a write model shouldn't depend on a read model.

Second, a domain event is implicitly a command to the consumers of the event: "process/consider/incorporate this event", in which case a write model processor can subscribe to the events arising from a different write model: from the perspective of the subscribing write model, these are just commands.

Comment: Would you say that a de-normalized write model is good practice?

Comment: I don't see a problem with a denormalized write model: once/if one reaches a point where you're deploying/evolving the models separately, there's a point where a denormalized write model becomes required for the write model to be autonomous.

Comment: Okay, but in order to keep the write model (be it normalized or not) autonomous, you ought not couple it to any particular read model?

Comment: You are correct.  But note that an event subscription is not a coupling which reduces the autonomy of the write model (if the read model is down/inaccessible, it simply doesn't get events)

Comment: Ok. But would you still call the „reading part“ of the write model (e.g. a denomalized materialized view) a read model, as suggested in your answer? To me, a read model is a truly independent model which ought not be consumed by the (or any) write model. Actually, the naming is kind of confusing. I‘d rather call one model the command processing model, and the others query processing models.

Comment: If there's nothing consuming a read model, why does the read model exist?

Comment: Anything (including people) consuming a read model is updating its view of the universe, i.e. is processing commands.

Comment: Sure, someone (people, a GUI, another microservice) will consume the read models. But **not** the write model. Imagine a command handler which first needs to call another read model (over web API or whatever) before applying changes to the write model. Also, now, the people/team owning that read model might deploy a change that breaks the command handler. Not good.

Comment: No command handler should make a query to a read model which isn't itself part of the command handler: it should only depend, ultimately, on the commands it receives.  This implies that the command handling module should either directly receive events (e.g. through pubsub messaging) from other command handlers or you have an adaptation process which is querying a read model and generating commands based on that.

Comment: It's important to note that both of those are asynchronous and eventually consistent.  If you have a business rule that actually has to be strongly consistent across aggregates, then in the context of anything that depends on that business rule, those are one aggregate.

Comment: Alright, so in my view, the command handling module (incl. the commands) and the write model go hand in hand (1:1), as the write model can only change through a command. I refer to both of them as simply the write model. So in that sense, it still holds that the write model should not depend on the read model (incl. the corresponding query module). Right?